# Server not found while trying out Ubuntu GNOME. Will this happen when I do a full install?

Tags: firefox, internet, live-usb, ubuntu-gnome

I am trying out Ubuntu GNOME without installing it. When I use Firefox, I get Server not found on every page but google.com. Will this happen when I do a full install?

Comment: Your network isn't fully up. It should be, but it's not. Are you using a wired or wireless connection?

Comment: I am using Wireless

Comment: Are you able to use a wired connection, and if so, does it work better? Connect wired, and disconnect from wireless to test.

Comment: I unfortunately can't use wired

Comment: Go ahead and install Ubuntu GNOME. Make sure it's 17.04. Wireless should work... but if there are still wireless problems, most can be fixed relatively quickly. Wireless is one of those things that there are so many different configurations, that sometimes problems can occur.